# MVC 5 using Azure AD cannot logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am using MVC5, authenticated the Azure AD using OpenIdConnect.

My application is running under 4 different Azure AD app registrations; localhost, a DEV version, a UAT version and the production version.

UAT and production are running under different deployment slots in the same web service on Azure.

Everything works perfectly apart from the logout functionality in the UAT deployment slot in Azure. When I click "logout" it takes me to the Microsoft logout  "You've signed out of your account". After I navigate back to the URL, it logs me back in (I have clicked "don't keep me signed in" too).

Any ideas on why this might be happening in a single environment? Azure AD app registration manifests are almost identical apart from the URLs and unique identifiers.

I am using the "UseKentorOwinCookieSaver" package.

Sign out method:

```
    public void SignOut()
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            );
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        OnAuth();
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                },                     
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
            }
        );

        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            // The function to call...
            OnAuth();
            return next.Invoke();
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your user credentials are likely being cached. This is the default behavior for Chrome and IE, and some of it is by design with Microsoft as well. The Single Sign Out you are aiming for requires custom coding on each application. Try logging in from a different browser in incognito mode to see if you still have this issue.

This thread provides some workarounds to your situation. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/97199b97-a3f1-42ab-b5dc-103d3bc3cb53/azure-ad-single-sign-on-auto-sign-in-with-windows-credentials?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't the problem. I have the same issue regardless of browser, or even different computers. The problem has been an issue with 3rd parties conducting testing outside of my own network.